# Passing bool parameter to powershell script shortcut

Tags: powershell, parameters, boolean, shortcut

I've written a powershell script that takes a bool parameter
I also have a windows shortcut to this powershell script.
The problem is that whenever I try to run the script from the shortcut, the parameter is interpreted as a string, not a bool, and the script crashes.

This is what I initially placed under the target section of my shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1" $true
```

I've searched for solutions online and tried the following options as well:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1" -copyAll:$true

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1" -copyAll:`$$true

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1" "`$$true"

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1" `$$true
```

And multiple such variations.

This is my question to you: Is there a way to send the value of a bool parameter to the script when running a from a windows shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1'" -copyAll:$true
```

of with `-file` parameter to pass `bool` to a switch parameter of your script try:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1" {-All:$False}
```

The last one is taked from [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx) but to be honest I'll never be able to work with it.

Comment: sorry, but the  space in Program files messes with Command  it just tries to run the script c:\Program and thinks the rest of the path is a parameter, while for your second approach I've got the following error: 
`Missing expression after unary operator '-'.At line:1 char:137
+ C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\diagnostic\DiagnosticTool.ps1" {- <<<< All:$true}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
`

Comment: that works. Thanks very much,
though I don't really know what & does in this particular case, but thanks.

Comment: @memoryofadream & is the 'Call operator', it lets you run commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings or enclosed in `'`/`"` as a string